# Pythonic way around Enums

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, parameters, enums

What is the *pythonic* way to tell the caller of a function what values a given parameter supports?

He is an example for PyQt (for GUI). Say I have a checkbox,

```
class checkbox(object):
    ....
    def setCheckState(self, value):
        ....
```

Here, `setCheckState()` should only expect **checked** or **unchecked**.

PyQt uses a built-in enumeration (i.e. `Qt.Checked` or `Qt.Unchecked`), but this is awful. I am constantly in the documentation looking for the enum for the object I am working with.

Obviously PyQt is written in an *unpythonic* C++ sytle. How *should* this or a similar problem be handled in Python? According to [PEP 435](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0435/), enums seem to be a recent addition to the language and for very specific applications, so I would assume there is/was a better way to handle this?

I want to make the code I write easy to use when my functions require specific parameter values--almost like a combobox for functions.

Comment: Enums were introduced precisely because everybody was using his own hacky replacement. If what you want is an enum, use an enum. If you have only two states, consider using a boolean: `def setCheckState(self, checked=True):`.

Comment: Inversion-of-control proponents would argue that there should be three separate functions that don't take *any* argument instead: `checkbox.set_checked()`, `checkbox.set_unchecked()`, and `checkbox.toggle()`.

Comment: I guess this is more opinion-based than I thought, I was hoping that like most things in Python, there would be _one_ right way to do it.

Comment: @chepner Can you explain the difference between `set_checked` & `set_unchecked` vs `set_checked_state(bool)`? Or e.g. `is_checked` property...

Comment: @zvone At the very least, it completely sidesteps the question of what values should be used to indicate which state. If you want to make the box checked, you don't worry about whether you should pass `1`, `True`, `"on"`, `"checked"`, or `SOME_CONSTANT` as an argument; you just call the very obvious `set_checked()` function.

Comment: See, in my understanding of the philosophy, you don't want strong types. If a function accepts an `int`, it should accept a `float` without error. This particular problem really breaks with that philosophy by only accepting _specific_ inputs. I think it would be bad practice to accept all the options (e.g. on, true, checked, etc.) because that would lead to everyone using your function differently--bad for changes later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *One Obvious Way* is function annotations.

```
class CheckBox(enum.Enum):
    Off = 0
    On = 1

def setCheckState(self, value: CheckBox):
    ...
```

This says quite clearly that `value` should be an instance of `CheckBox`.  Having `Enum` just makes that a bit easier.

Annotations themselves aren't directly supported in 2.7, though.  Common workarounds include putting that information in the function doc string (where various tools can find it) or in comments (as we already knew).

If looking for a method for your own code: use an annotating decorator.  This has the advantage of continuing to work in 3+:

```
class annotate(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwds):
        self.kwds = kwds
    def __call__(self, func):
        func.__annotations__ = self.kwds

@annotate(value=CheckBox)
def setCheckState(self, value):
    ...
```

To be a robust decorator it should check that the contents of `kwds` matches the function parameter names.

Comment: Function annotations aren't available in Python 2.7.

Comment: That would explain why I haven't heard of them before now.

Comment: Ah, I missed the 2.7 tag, sorry.

Comment: For reference, [PEP 3107](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/) is the document on function annotations. I'm reading through it now anyway.

Answer (score 0):

That will do the trick

```
import collections

def create_enum(container, start_num, *enum_words):
    return collections.namedtuple(container, enum_words)(*range(start_num, start_num + len(enum_words)))

Switch = create_enum('enums', 1, 'On', 'Off')
```

*Switch* is your enum:

```
In [20]: Switch.On
Out[20]: 1

In [21]: Switch.Off
Out[21]: 2
```

OK, I got the error of my ways - I mixed up representation with value.

Nevertheless, if you want to enumerate a larger range - in my **fake** approach you don't have to add values manually. Of course, if you have sequential numbers.

And I hate extra typing :-)

Comment: Python has `Enum` now, no need to create fake ones.

Comment: @EthanFurman, unfortunately, values of Switch.Off and Switch on, created with enum, are not 0 and 1 - they are types and you need further dereference to get 0 and 1.

Comment: Not if you use `enum.IntEnum`.

Comment: @EthanFurman, gotcha. I actually don't use enums - I just re-patched a method I use to create wrapper objects for constants.

Comment: You may want to check out [`aenum`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum/1.4.5).  Besides advanced enums it also has NamedConstant and a metaclass-based NamedTuple.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125749/discussion-between-ethan-furman-and-volcano).