# Python: enumerated values vs. nameduples

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, enumeration

Recently I participated in a discussion about [enumeration in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40028498/pythonic-way-around-enums/40030794#40030794). [Ethan Furman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/208880/ethan-furman) has suggested that there's no need to re-invent the wheel, and when there're standard *enum* package - no need to play around.

So, after finally switching to 3.5, I tried - and it turns out that string constants defined by *enum.Enum* **do require** de-referencing, at least in some APIs.

This is a simplified example of what did not work for me

```
In [83]: consts = collections.namedtuple('consts', 'PATH')('/usr/bin')

In [84]: consts.PATH
Out[84]: '/usr/bin'

In [85]: os.path.exists(consts.PATH)
Out[85]: True

In [86]: consts = enum.Enum('consts', [['PATH','/usr/bin']])

In [87]: os.path.exists(consts.PATH)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-87-c4641f1a4c50> in <module>()
----> 1 os.path.exists(consts.PATH)

/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/genericpath.py in exists(path)
     17     """Test whether a path exists.  Returns False for broken symbolic links"""
     18     try:
---> 19         os.stat(path)
     20     except OSError:
     21         return False

TypeError: argument should be string, bytes or integer, not consts
```

That, of course, worked

```
In [90]: os.path.exists(consts.PATH.value)
Out[90]: True
```

In my book, any approach that requires adding code all over the project is guilty of being inefficient, so - while thankful for the suggestion! - I am going back to good ol' *namedtuple* approach.

The question is - why doesn't *enum* attribute supports implicit dereferencing of attributes? Is it implementation bug in 3.5.2?

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`enum.Enum` is meant to be a base class. If you also inherit from `str` as you're setting up the class, it should work as expected:

```
In [34]: class consts(str, enum.Enum):
   ....:     PATH = r"C:\Windows"
   ....:

In [35]: consts.PATH
Out[35]: <consts.PATH: 'C:\\Windows'>

In [36]: os.path.exists(consts.PATH)
Out[36]: True
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I am too used to implicit casting in Python, it seems.